# Getting a segmentation fault when trying to write a Breadth First Search method to a graph

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have commented out some things I have used to test my code, but the main problem is that when I run this I get a segmentation fault, you can see that I have commented out a function method that was originally supposed to complete the Breadth First Search. [This is what happens when I compile the code using g++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYAhR.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

struct Edge
{
  int src, dest;
};

class Graph
{
private:
  vector<vector<int>> adjList;
  int N;
  friend class BFS;

public:
  Graph() : N(0){};
  Graph(const Graph &orig) : N(orig.N)
  {
    vector<vector<int>> adjList = orig.adjList;
  }
  Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N) : N(N)
  {

    adjList.resize(N);
    for (auto &edge : edges)
    {
      adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);
    }
  }
  friend void printGraph(Graph const &graph);

  void addEdge(Edge &e)
  {
    if (e.src < N && e.dest < N)
    {
      adjList[e.src].push_back(e.dest);
    }
    else if (e.src == N || e.dest == N)
    {
      adjList.resize(++N);
      adjList[e.src].push_back(e.dest);
    }
    else if (e.src >= N || e.dest >= N)
    {
      cout << "ERROR: you cannot add a edge to a vertex more than 1 greater than old greatest vertex" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }
  }
  /*
  int *BFS(int start)
  {
    int cur = 0;
    int node;
    int len = this->N;
    static int *level = new int[len];
    for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)
    {
      level[a] = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    }
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(start);
    q.push(-1);

    while (!q.empty())
    {
      node = q.front();
      if (node == -1)
      {
        cur++;
        q.push(-1);
      }
      else
      {
        level[node] = cur;
      }
      q.pop();
      for (int count = 0; count < this->adjList[node].size(); count++)
      {
        if (level[count] == numeric_limits<int>::max())
        {
          q.push(count);
        }
      }
    }
    return level;
  }
  */

  int size()
  {
    return N;
  }

  void DFS() const
  {
  }
};

class BFS
{
private:
  int cur;
  int node;
  int len;
  int start;
  int *level;
  queue<int> q;

public:
  BFS(Graph &g, int start) : cur(0), len(g.N), level(new int[len]), start(start)
  {
    for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)
    {
      level[a] = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    }
    q.push(start);
    q.push(-1);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
      node = q.front();
      if (node == -1)
      {
        cur++;
        q.push(-1);
      }
      else
      {
        level[node] = cur;
      }
      q.pop();
      for (int count = 0; count < g.adjList[node].size(); count++)
      {
        if (level[count] == numeric_limits<int>::max())
        {
          q.push(count);
        }
      }
    }
    cout << "vertex"
         << "\tlevel" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      cout << i << "\t" << level[i] << endl;
    }
  }
  ~BFS()
  {
    delete[] level;
  }
};

void printGraph(Graph const &graph)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < graph.N; i++)
  {
    cout << i << " ——> ";
    for (int v : graph.adjList[i])
    {
      cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{

  vector<Edge> edges =
      {
          {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 4}};

  Graph graph(edges, 6);
  //Edge e = {6, 5, };
  // cout << e.src << "\t" << e.dest << endl;
  //graph.addEdge(e);
  printGraph(graph);
  //int *p = graph.BFS(0);
  cout << "______________________" << endl;
  BFS b(graph, 0);
  /*
  for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << i << "\t" << *(p + i) << endl;
  }
*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One way to not have segmentation faults is to reduce, if not eliminate the need for raw pointers.  You are using `std::vector` in your code, but you failed to use it here: `static int *level = new int[len];`.  This could have simply been `static std::vector<int> level(len);`.  The second thing is to remove code that you've commented out.   There is no need to post an entire screen of commented-out code.

Comment: `int *level;` -- This is not initialized.  Also if the intent was to call `new[]` to initialize it, don't do it.  Instead (and again): `std::vector<int> level;` and then initialize it with a size, `resize()` it, `push_back`, etc.  Remove the need to make that a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check line 140. There is something wrong with

```
if (level[count] == numeric_limits<int>::max())
```

GDB from
https://www.onlinegdb.com/
says when count have value 32912 there is sigsev. Probably some problem with array length.

edit:
You can use vector or if you relay want arrays in c++11 there is std::array type.